# "breaks" argument in visreg with multiple predictors

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, interaction, mixed-models

I am trying to plot the predicted probabilities from a set of binomial `glmer` objects produced using package `lme4`. They are of the form:

```
library(lme4)
model = glmer(
  LogFlag ~ FRI + Mound + woody + (1 | ID) + 
    (0 + FRI | ID) + (0 + Mound | ID) +
    (0 + woody | ID)  + Mound:FRI + Mound:woody, 
  family = "binomial", 
  data = BBmod
)
```

To make the plots I am using calls to `visreg` as follows:

```
visreg(
  model, xvar = "FRI", by = "Mound", scale = "response", 
  rug = 0, overlay = T, partial = F, gg = T, 
  breaks = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 15, 20, 40, 80), 
  band = F, line = list(col = rainbow(9)), legend = F
)
```

This usually produces very nice plots with `FRI` on the x-axis, probability on the y-axis, and 9 separate lines for the values of Mound specified in the `breaks` argument.

My question is what value of `woody`, the third predictor, is being used? Without any `breaks` argument, visreg defaults to using the median of predictors not included in the call, but I have given `breaks` for `Mound`. How can I specify, or at least confirm, the value of woody that is being used?

Answer (score 1):

I was confusing the `breaks` and `cond` arguments. The documentation shows that with

```
cond = list(woody = Z)
```

I can control the value of woody, where `Z` is the value of `woody`. Maybe this will help someone.